# Recursively renaming files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Calling this powershell command and getting an error.  Driving me nuts.

```
Prompt> get-childitem -recurse ./ *NYCSCA* |  where-object { $_.Name -like
 "*NYCSCA*" } |  rename-item $_ -newname $_.Name.Replace(" ","_") -whatif
```

Here is the response:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:140
+ get-childitem -recurse ./ *NYCSCA* |  where-object { $_.Name -like "*NYCSCA*" } | select FullName | rename-item $_ -n
ewname $_.Name.Replace <<<< (" ","_") -whatif
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Replace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

If I remove the last part, I get a list of files.  Any clues?  I have not grocked powershell yet, obviously.

Note: I tried to post this to superuser, but the site is consistently failing now - won't let me add this exact question.

Here it is greatly simplified.  I cannot even get this classic example to work.

```
gci  *NYCSCA*  | ren $_ ($_.Name).Replace("foo","bar")
```

Thank you @JNK, the % did it.  The solution I needed is this, in case you're interested:

```
gci -recurse | where-object{ $_.Name -like "*NYCSCA*"} | %{rename-item $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace("NYCSCA","SDUSD") }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21614001/8479

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need foreach-object:

```
get-childitem -recurse ./ *NYCSCA* |  where-object { $_.Name -like
 "*NYCSCA*" } | % {rename-item $_ -newname $_.Name.Replace(" ","_") -whatif}
```

The piped array can't be renamed as a set.

Comment: Yes!  That is it - thank you.  I need to understand sets versus items better.  But this is great!

Comment: Glad it helped.  My first step anytime I have a pipe not work is to try a foreach-object.

Comment: When powershell drops down into a folder to do the renaming there it complains that the file doesn't exist. How could I solve that building off your example?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I would post a new question about it. It's probably related to the exact syntax you're using.

Comment: This command doesn't seem to work right with subdirectories as @TheMuffinMan reported. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21614001/8479 instead.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simplified version to rename files only

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *NYCSCA* -Recurse |
 Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
 Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace(' ','_') } -WhatIf
```

(*Edit: line breaks added for clarity*)

Comment: The real difference here is using code blocks `{...}` in `rename-item` arguments to allow reference to `$_` (which is why `foreach-object` also provides a solution.

Comment: True, foreach-object does the job but it adds overhead (and is slower).

Comment: Interesting, so this lets rename-item treat its arguments as a set, rather than having rename-items called within a set of operations of the foreach.