# Overwrite existing file and Rename

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename a file `Members.csv`.

```cs
Get-ChildItem ".\" -Filter '*Members*.csv' | where {
    $_.LastWriteTime.GetDateTimeFormats()[44] -eq $today
} | Rename-Item -NewName "hello2.csv" -Force
```

`-Force` is not working. If hello2 exists already the renaming will not take place.

I found this thread saying that we have to use `Move-Item`. but I am not sure how to incorporate it in my code.

[rename-item and override if filename exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311875/rename-item-and-override-if-filename-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
Get-ChildItem index.*.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = $_.Name -replace "^(index\.)(.*)",'$2'
    $Destination = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $NewName
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination -Force
}
```

I am not trying to replace, I'm renaming the entire name so I don't know what to do for this part:

```
$NewName = $_.Name = "hello2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Force` parameter of `Rename-Item` does not allow you to replace an existing file by renaming another. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-3.0):

> **-Force**
>
> Forces the cmdlet to rename items that cannot otherwise be changed, such as hidden or read-only files or read-only aliases or variables. The cmdlet cannot change constant aliases or variables. Implementation varies from provider to provider. For more information, see about_Providers.

You need to use `Move-Item -Force`, as you already found out, and it's used in exactly the same way you're trying to use `Rename-Item` in your first code snippet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*Members*.csv' | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime.GetDateTimeFormats()[44] -eq $today
} | Move-Item -Destination "hello2.csv" -Force
```

Beware that if after the `Where-Object` you have more than one item, each of them will replace the previous one, so you'll effectively end up removing all but one of them.