# Replace Part of Filename if Filename Already Exists

Tags: powershell

In this question, How do I rename part of a filename, if the newly renamed  filename already exists? Want the newly attempted filename to overwrite the existing file. Also want to rename folders within folders within folders.

Replace "Default" with "VOD" in filename,

[Replace Part of File Name Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182409/replace-part-of-file-name-powershell)

```
Get-ChildItem Default_*.csv |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^Default','VOD'}

ls *.csv | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "Default","VOD"}
```

Solution here was not working with `-Force`:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -File -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'Default','VOD'} -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this question and answer: [rename-item and override if filename exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311875/rename-item-and-override-if-filename-exists)

Use `Move-Item` and `-Destination`, and also swap `$_.Name` for `$_.FullName` (if you don't do that it will throw everything into your current directory, because `Name` is just the name of the file, not the full path). Check using `-WhatIf` to see what operations will be carried out, just in case:

**With `-WhatIf`:**

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -File  -Recurse |
    Move-Item -Destination {$_.FullName -replace 'Default','VOD'} -WhatIf
```

**Output:**

> What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\pstest\Default_77.txt Destination: C:\temp\pstest\VOD_77.txt".

**Now with `-Force`:**

When you're comfortable with the output from using the `-WhatIf` parameter, change it to `-Force` to complete the file move.

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -File  -Recurse | 
    Move-Item -Destination {$_.FullName -replace 'Default','VOD'} -Force
```