# Using the rename-item command to overwrite an existing file?

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I'm trying to tidy up imported files from my iPhone using a PowerShell script, specifically wanting edited photos (IMG_E001.jpg) to overwrite the non-edited photos (IMG_001.jpg).

I'm using the `rename-item` but can't figure out how to get it to overwrite the file. My current workaround is to move all of the edited files into their own folder, run the script, and then copy them over the top of the original files but this is a bit of a pain, plus it doesn't seem as reliable as a fully automated script.

Here's the code I'm using currently:

```
get-childitem -recurse -Include *.JPG | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("E", "") };
```

Please can anyone help me to get this script to overwrite the existing files? Thank you

Comment: Try adding a `-Force` like so: `Get-Childitem -Recurse -Filter *.JPG | Foreach-Object -Process { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.Replace("E", "") -Force }`

Comment: If that didn't work you'll need to delete the non-edited files first and then rename.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue or feature. Windows does not allow you to rename a file an existing file of the same name.  It's an OS operational filesystem boundary. Thus the two-step this you have encountered. There are ways to do it in a single step.

Comment: Thank you @AbrahamZinala , unfortunately that gave an `Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` error so I think these guys are right that I need to move or remove the files first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of **rename-item** as @postanote mentioned in his comment this is because windows does not allow you to rename a file to an existing name. You will need to remove the other file first or overwrite it. Instead you can use **move-item -force** for essentially the same effect as it will perform the overwrite.

```
get-childitem -recurse -Include *.txt | foreach { Move-Item $_ $_.Name.Replace("E", "") -Force };
```

For more information; here is a related thread [rename-item and override if filename exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311875/rename-item-and-override-if-filename-exists)